# Private Cloud SQL on phpMyAdmin (AppEngine)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've followed the [following tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine) step by step.

I've tried the following:

- Installing the App Engine phpMyAdmin on the same project as my Cloud SQL server.
- Installing it a different project and adding the right IAM roles (Cloud SQL Admin)

I can't for the life of me get it to connect. I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Check if connection_name is well written, it should be something like *projectID:region:instanceName*. Does your network configuration of the App Engine Aplication is the default or did you made a change? Try doing the: [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql] to see if it's a problem with the SQL instance.

Comment: @NahuelVarelaBlanco The connection name is well written. However it is `$host = "/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>"`

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how you are trying to connect based on the info you have provided. To connect on App Engine, you need to use the provided unix domain socket at `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>` (the instance connection name can be found on your instances details page, and is in the format `<project>:<region>:<instance>`).

For more details on connecting from App Engine, check out the [Connecting from App Engine page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine).

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I am doing. I noted the link I followed 100% to a T and it does not work.

Comment: @bryan Does the error appear in your AppEngine logs?